# Manually signing a 3rd Party dll looses file details

Tags: c#, dll, strongname, ildasm

I have used these steps to sign a **3rd party C# .Net Dll**: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/miah/2008/02/28/how-to-assign-a-strong-name-to-an-unsigned-3rd-party-assembly/

Using these steps:

```
ILDASM.exe SomeLibrary.dll /OUTPUT=SomeLibrary.il
ILASM.exe SomeLibrary.il /DLL /OUTPUT=SomeLibrary.dll /KEY=key.snk
```

But I have noticed that the output dll that is now signed has lost all its original file details:

[image]

How can I preserve the original file details?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ILASM does not set FileVersion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9192145/11683)

Comment: If your goal is to sign the assemblies and later use them as references, then please simply use tools like Strong Namer https://github.com/dsplaisted/strongnamer or Sign References, https://github.com/picrap/SignReferences